# Putting first solution of three NDsolve into an array and plotting

Tags: differential-equations, differential-geometry

Suppose I have three differential equations systems, each one of them has 4 equations. 
I find the 4 solutions of each one, let's call them x,y,z,w. Now, I want to take $x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$ and put them in an array so I can plot it by letting t vary. 
This array would be:
$$ \alpha(t) = \{x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t)\} $$
Then I also want to take $y_i$,$z_i$ and $w_i$ to to the same. If you are curious $\alpha$ would be my curve and then the other is the Frenet tried.

However I am struggling to to this, for alpha I would do this in Mathematica:

```
alpha[t_] := {x[t] /. Part[solution1[[1]], 1], 
              y[t] /. Part[solution2[[1]], 1], 
              z[t] /. Part[solution3[[1]], 1]}
```

However It doesn't seem to work, because I then try to plot Alpha like this:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[alpha[t]], {t, 0, 6}]
```

But I get an empty cube.

Solution is given from the NDSolve. The code `Part[solution1[[1]],1]` is mean to take the array of solutions, and then the first one because that would be x.

I also tried to do: `x[t] /. solution[[1]]` etc etc, that seemed too work just fine for $\alpha$, but then failed for the other things because it keeps saying that the solution[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elqH1.png)], solution[[3]] and solution[[4]] do not exist (even though I have those).

Do you see what did I do wrong?

EDIT: Added picture of form of solution1
[image]
Where v[t],k1[t], k2[t] are given functions of t.

And this is what solution1 looks like:
[image]

Comment: does `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Through[alpha[t]]], {t, 0, 6}]` work?

Comment: What are the forms of the solutions, `solution1`,...?  To figure out what's with someone else's code often requires the complete code.

Comment: @kglr No it doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Edited the question with more info, let me know if you need more.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `Part` and use `x[t] /. solution1[[1]]`, etc.?  Alternatively, change the `y` component to `y[t] /. Part[solution2[[1]], 2]` or equivalently, `y[t] /. solution2[[1, 2]]`; similarly for `z`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always share complete information along with copyable *Mathematica* syntax.

I suspect that the empty plot is because of extra curls around the entries in `alpha[t]`. If we go to the documentation of `ParametricPlot3D`, the syntax is `ParametricPlot3D[{fx, fy, fz},{u, a, b}]`. I'm guessing that your `alpha[t]` structure  is `{{fx},{fy},{fz}}`, which is causing the problem.

Anyways, here is an example to follow,

```
v[t_] = Sin[t];

k1[t_] = Cos[t];

k2[t_] = 5;

a = 0; b = 10;

Eq1 = x'[t] - v[t]*y[t] == 0;

Eq2 = y'[t] - v[t]*k1[t]*z[t] == 0;

Eq3 = z'[t] + v[t]*k1[t]*y[t] + v[t]*k2[t]*w[t] == 0;

Eq4 = w'[t] - v[t]*k2[t]*z[t] == 0;

sol1 = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0, 
    w[0] == 0}, {x, y, z, w}, {t, a, b}];

Eq41 = w'[t] - 1/2*v[t]*k2[t]*z[t] == 0;

sol2 = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq41, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0, 
    w[0] == 0}, {x, y, z, w}, {t, a, b}];

Eq21 = 2*y'[t] - v[t]*k1[t]*z[t] == 0;

sol3 = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq21, Eq3, Eq41, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0,
     w[0] == 0}, {x, y, z, w}, {t, a, b}];

alpha[t_] = {x[t] /. sol1, y[t] /. sol2, z[t] /. sol3};

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Flatten[alpha[t]]], {t, a, b}]
```